# Facebook share button in modal iframe?

Tags: facebook, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, modal-dialog, share

I am trying to get Facebook share option in bootstrap popup (modal). Is there any options to embed share windows in bootstrap modal? Facebook dosen't allow iframe for share buttons. Any idea how this might work?

Comment: you want the share button to be in the modal?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Social Plugins wherever you want, but if they are created dynamically (which may be the case in the modal popup) you have to parse the code again, after the HTML code is created:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/

Comment: I'm using plugin for laravel to parse URL, so i dont know how to parse it through Facebook SDK

Comment: this is what you need then: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart
that, and a javascript call to FB.XFBML.parse()